# Selenium Java - new Actions(driver)).sendKeys(...) behaviour

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using the following code to send some keys to the browser window:

```
(new Actions(driver)).sendKeys(StringToBeEntered).perform();
```

My question is does it make a difference to the functioning of sendKeys if the String being passed to it is a predefined String variable as opposed to an actual String constant?

Is `sendKeys(strVariable).perform()` and `sendKeys("String").perform` going to have the same behavior?

I'm using this method because the element to which text needs to be send is being not selectable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it makes no difference.

```
String strVariable = "String"
sendKeys(strVariable).perform();
```

And...

```
sendKeys("String").perform();
```

... are identical in Selenium.

The reason is nothing to do with Selenium but the way Java works. It's a bit complicated to explain, but in Java variables in methods are passed *by value*, not by reference. So, in the first version, the value of the variable (i.e. the string) is passed into the method, not the variable reference itself. Which means, as far as the sendKeys() method is concerned, the first and second versions are identical.

It is also important to point out that Strings in Java are immutable, so neither the sendKeys method nor anything outside of the method could change the value of the String itself.

Comment: The end result is correct, but Strings are technically objects, not primitive, and so the reference to the string is passed by value.  However, I think this is a great answer to a question which could have had a simple, dull one. +1